# PHPMailer: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```
function send_mail($message, $subject)
{
    if (array_key_exists('resume', $_FILES))
    {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['resume']['name']));
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
        {
           require './PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
           $mail              = new PHPMailer;
           $mail->isSMTP();
           $mail->SMTPDebug   = 1;
           $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
           $mail->Host        = 'smtp.gmail.com';
           $mail->Port        = 587;
           $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            
           $mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
           $mail->Username    = "abc@gmail.com";
           $mail->Password    = "XXXX";
           $mail->SetFrom('abc@gmail.com', 'ABC');
           $mail->AddAddress('abc@gmail.com');
           $mail->Subject = $subject;
           $mail->MsgHTML($message);
           $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
           $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile);

           if ($mail->Send())
           {
               echo "<script>alert('Your application is sent successfully. Our recruitment team will get in touch with you soon.');</script>";
           }
           else
           {
               echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

           }
       }
       else
       {
           echo 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
       }
   }
```

}

I am getting below mentioned Error:

```
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
CLIENT -> SERVER: ZGV0ZWN0aW9uaW5zdHJ1bWVudEBnbWFpbC5jb20=
CLIENT -> SERVER: ZGV0ZWN0aW9uaW5kaWE=
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14          <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuk534-5.7.14 PHxasqAG-1Yi0Ij1bFvZdQIBCbXiwU2i-qOUAnhhTN-mHhCHRat1ivgXGVmBuQTk0cJTl2534-5.7.14 7kvt6yrXWWs9R8Rz1mxkje545Mg0F7Xx3Cl1VTW33gDBxGfcVfR-pIVPd1SIqMHWdICkLz534-5.7.14 pPL3_DNms_IS8jJkz3Eo3MH91Yq1OU3XUV1EXzfxaUA7xbYyK9jbwM1XVvVQ-NqqYYKCMY534-5.7.14 uNWA9kWIDl_XXYWrNNP6_cCiWomH8> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 bb5sm14055457pac.21 - gsmtp
```

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: You'd have more idea if you followed the advice in the troubleshooting guide your error message linked to. For a start set `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see the server messages.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to enable [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

---

> Change account access for less secure apps
>
> To help keep Google Apps users' accounts secure, we may block less
>   secure apps from accessing Google Apps accounts. As a Google Apps
>   user, you will see a "Password incorrect" error when trying to sign
>   in. If this is the case, you have two options:
>
> 1. Option 1: Upgrade to a more secure app that uses the most up to date
>      security measures. All Google products, like Gmail, use the latest
>      security measures.
> 2. Option 2: Change your settings to allow less secure apps to access
>      your account. We don't recommend this option because it might make
>      it easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to
>      allow access anyway, follow these steps:
>
>    2.1. Go to the "[Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563)" section in My Account
>
>    2.2. Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to
>      Google Apps users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account access.)
>
> If you still can't sign in to your account, the "[password
>   incorrect](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563)" error might be caused by a different reason.

SRC: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

---

**NOTE:**

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

and enable debug on PHPMAILER

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                       // 1 = errors and messages
                       // 2 = messages only
```

to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but  "Less secure apps" is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but only when trying to connect from heroku.
If I try to connect from 000webhost it works with either ssl or tls...

I would prefer not to try with app password strategy (two-factor authentication) but it seems there is nothing else I can try.